# Error Chapter 10 Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Hi I'm working on the tutorial and stumped on this error. I have tried to create a controller "create_reset_digest" but still working. I'm pretty new to rails. Thanks:

```
    ERROR["test_password_resets", PasswordResetsTest, 3.338488]
     test_password_resets#PasswordResetsTest (3.34s)
    NoMethodError:         NoMethodError: undefined method `reset_digest=' for #<User:0x007fed452318f8>
                app/models/user.rb:57:in `create_reset_digest'
                app/controllers/password_resets_controller.rb:12:in `create'
                test/integration/password_resets_test.rb:17:in `block in <class:PasswordResetsTest>'
            app/models/user.rb:57:in `create_reset_digest'
            app/controllers/password_resets_controller.rb:12:in `create'
            test/integration/password_resets_test.rb:17:in `block in <class:PasswordResetsTest>'
```

Here is the code that I'm having issues with:
---user.rb

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessor :remember_token, :activation_token, :reset_token
  before_save   :downcase_email
  before_create :create_activation_digest
  validates :name,  presence: true, length: { maximum: 50 }
  VALID_EMAIL_REGEX = /\A[\w+\-.]+@[a-z\-.]+\.[a-z]+\z/i
  validates :email, presence: true, length: { maximum: 255 },
                    format: { with: VALID_EMAIL_REGEX },
                    uniqueness: { case_sensitive: false }
  has_secure_password
  validates :password, length: { minimum: 6 }, allow_blank: true

  # Returns the hash digest of the given string.
  def User.digest(string)
    cost = ActiveModel::SecurePassword.min_cost ? BCrypt::Engine::MIN_COST : 
                                                  BCrypt::Engine.cost
    BCrypt::Password.create(string, cost: cost)
  end

  # Returns a random token.
  def User.new_token
    SecureRandom.urlsafe_base64
  end

  # Remembers a user in the database for use in persistent sessions.
  def remember
    self.remember_token = User.new_token
    update_attribute(:remember_digest, User.digest(remember_token))
  end

  # Forgets a user.
  def forget
    update_attribute(:remember_digest, nil)
  end

  # Returns true if the given token matches the digest.
  def authenticated?(attribute, token)
    digest = send("#{attribute}_digest")
    return false if digest.nil?
    BCrypt::Password.new(digest).is_password?(token)
  end

  # Activates an account.
  def activate
    update_attribute(:activated,    true)
    update_attribute(:activated_at, Time.zone.now)    
  end

  # Sends activation email.
  def send_activation_email
    UserMailer.account_activation(self).deliver_now
  end

  # Sets the password reset attributes.
  def create_reset_digest
    self.reset_token = User.new_token
    update_attribute(:reset_digest, User.digest(reset_token))
    update_attribute(:reset_sent_at, Time.zone.now)
  end

  # Sends password reset email.
  def send_password_reset_email
    UserMailer.password_reset(self).deliver_now
  end

  # Returns true if a password reset has expired.
  def password_reset_expired?
    reset_sent_at < 2.hours.ago
  end

  private

    # Converts email to all lower-case.
    def downcase_email
      self.email = email.downcase
    end

    # Creates and assigns the activation token and digest.
    def create_activation_digest
      self.activation_token  = User.new_token
      self.activation_digest = User.digest(activation_token)
    end
end
```

--password_resets_controller.rb

```
class PasswordResetsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :get_user,         only: [:edit, :update]
  before_action :valid_user,       only: [:edit, :update]
  before_action :check_expiration, only: [:edit, :update]

  def new
  end



  def create
    @user = User.find_by(email: params[:password_reset][:email].downcase)
    if @user
      @user.create_reset_digest
      @user.send_password_reset_email
      flash[:info] = "Email sent with password reset instructions"
      redirect_to root_url
    else
      flash.now[:danger] = "Email address not found"
      render 'new'
    end
  end

  def edit
  end

  def update
    if both_passwords_blank?
      flash.now[:danger] = "Password/confirmation can't be blank"
      render 'edit'
    elsif @user.update_attributes(user_params)
      log_in @user
      flash[:success] = "Password has been reset."
      redirect_to @user
    else
      render 'edit'
    end
  end

  private

    def user_params
      params.require(:user).permit(:password, :password_confirmation)
    end

    # Returns true if password & confirmation are blank.
    def both_passwords_blank?
      params[:user][:password].blank? && 
      params[:user][:password_confirmation].blank?
    end

    # Before filters

    def get_user
      @user = User.find_by(email: params[:email])
    end

    # Confirms a valid user.
    def valid_user
      unless (@user && @user.activated? && 
              @user.authenticated?(:reset, params[:id]))
        redirect_to root_url
      end      
    end

    # Checks expiration of reset token.
    def check_expiration
      if @user.password_reset_expired?
        flash[:danger] = "Password reset has expired."
        redirect_to new_password_reset_url
      end
    end
end
```

---password_resets_test.rb

```
require 'test_helper'

class PasswordResetsTest < ActionDispatch::IntegrationTest
  def setup
    ActionMailer::Base.deliveries.clear
    @user = users(:michael)
  end

  test "password resets" do
    get new_password_reset_path
    assert_template 'password_resets/new'
    # Invalid email
    post password_resets_path, password_reset: { email: "" }
    assert_not flash.empty?
    assert_template 'password_resets/new'
    # Valid email
    post password_resets_path, password_reset: { email: @user.email }
    assert_not_equal @user.reset_digest, @user.reload.reset_digest
    assert_equal 1, ActionMailer::Base.deliveries.size
    assert_not flash.empty?
    assert_redirected_to root_url
    # Password reset form
    user = assigns(:user)
    # Wrong email
    get edit_password_reset_path(user.reset_token, email: "")
    assert_redirected_to root_url
    # Inactive user
    user.toggle!(:activated)
    get edit_password_reset_path(user.reset_token, email: user.email)
    assert_redirected_to root_url
    user.toggle!(:activated)
    # Right email, wrong token
    get edit_password_reset_path('wrong token', email: user.email)
    assert_redirected_to root_url
    # Right email, right token
    get edit_password_reset_path(user.reset_token, email: user.email)
    assert_template 'password_resets/edit'
    assert_select "input[name=email][type=hidden][value=?]", user.email
    # Invalid password & confirmation
    patch password_reset_path(user.reset_token),
          email: user.email,
          user: { password:              "foobaz",
                  password_confirmation: "barquux" }
    assert_select 'div#error_explanation'
    # Blank password & confirmation
    patch password_reset_path(user.reset_token),
          email: user.email,
          user: { password:              "  ",
                  password_confirmation: "  " }
    assert_not flash.empty?
    assert_template 'password_resets/edit'
    # Valid password & confirmation
    patch password_reset_path(user.reset_token),
          email: user.email,
          user: { password:              "foobaz",
                  password_confirmation: "foobaz" }
    assert is_logged_in?
    assert_not flash.empty?
    assert_redirected_to user
  end
end
```

Comment: Please provide a link to the tutorial you are using. If it is not online, then an excerpt of the code that triggers the error would be useful.

Comment: hmm it's most probably a migration issue. try running `rake db:migrate` then try resetting your password again.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I ran into a very similar problem at chapter 10 with `create_activation_digest` in `app/models/user.rb`.
My problem was assigning value to a non-existing attribute:
In the tutorial it says

```
self.activation_token  = User.new_token.
```

but `activation_token` is not an attribute of `User`.
Hence, make sure `reset_digest` is really an attribute of the `User` table.
Have a look at the migration files, and run

```
rake db:migrate
```

if this attribute appears.